# How to implement both generic and non-generic version of a class?

Tags: c#, generics

I want to implement a non-generic version of my generic class. Like this.

```
public class ServerSentEvent : ServerSentEvent<NoAdditionalClientInformation>

public class ServerSentEvent<ClientInfo> : IServerSentEvent
```

To solve this I had to make a dummy/empty class - NoAdditionalClientInformation.

Is there another way to do this without the empty class?

Comment: do you know the type when you say non generic of generic? if yes then just use it..

Comment: If you look at .NET BCL classes you will notice that the generic versions are child classes of the non generic versions and not the other way round. For example `IEnumerable<T>` implements `IEnumerable`.

Comment: What if the generic class inherited from the non-generic one: `public class ServerSentEvent<TClientInfo> : ServerSentEvent` and `public class ServerSentEvent : IServerSentEvent`?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov can you give an example of generic *class* that a child of non-generic?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, you are correct. This happens with interfaces only, not with classes.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky `ChannelFactory<TChannel>` inherits from `ChannelFactory`

Comment: Can't it be just `public class ServerSentEvent : IServerSentEvent`?

Comment: @mikez we've got one :) Well, usually as Darin said in last comment, generic classes just implement non-generic and generic interfaces

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Usually you’d just do it the other way around:

```
public class ServerSentEvent : IServerSentEvent
{}

public class ServerSentEvent<ClientInfo> : ServerSentEvent
{}
```

That way the generic version is a more specified subtype of the non-generic one allowing you to put more information in it but to use the generic type whereever a non-generic type is expected.

If you do it like you suggested, you would need to have to specify some *default* type; if you can’t think of a default one, it is probably the wrong order, but in general it might depend on the case.

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed example?

Comment: @Saibot For what exactly? Maybe you should ask your own question?

Comment: Yeah, then it would be marked as duplicate in 10 seconds :D

Comment: I would like to see a case where we can benefit implementing both generic and non generic versions. I am having trouble to understand why this is necessary (or is it necessary at all?) and how to use this pattern properly.

Comment: @Saibot As an example, see `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable`. `IEnumerable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable`, so every generic enumerable is also a non-generic enumerable. The benefit of this is that anything that works with any enumerable will also work for generic enumerables. Another example would be `Task<T>` and `Task`.